# Auto growing text area issue using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea

I have this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/79432) which tries to implement auto growing textarea using React.

I am storing the textarea styles containing only height as 40px by default and then gradually increasing its height using the element's scrollHeight as we type more content in the textarea.

But it is not working and keeps increasing the height by 10px for every character I type.

Could someone help me out with this issue.

**Here the whole code:**

```
class MyTextArea extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.textAreaStyle = {
      height: '40px'
    };

    this.state = {
      textValue: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    let height = this.textArea.scrollHeight;
    this.textAreaStyle = {
      height
    };
  }

  trackContent(event) {
    this.setState({
      textValue: event.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
        <textarea 
          onChange={ this.trackContent.bind(this) }
          ref={(el) => { this.textArea = el } }
          style={ this.textAreaStyle }
          value={ this.state.textValue } 
        />
    </div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyTextArea />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

**Gif of the behaviour**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/79433/

Maybe try to compare with offsetHeight.

Alternatively, use a `contentedtiable` div

```js
function check_height()
{
  var box = document.getElementById("box");
  let height = box.offsetHeight;

  if (height < box.scrollHeight)
  {
   box.style.height = box.scrollHeight + "px";
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea id="box" onkeyup="check_height()">
  
</textarea>

<div contenteditable style="min-height: 20px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black;">
<div>
```

And rather than using `value` maybe use `defaultValue` instead.